# web3.eth.getBalance always returns zero

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle-migration

I am new to Ethereum and i'm building a dapp by following this tutorial here

https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f

I have started geth node in Ropsten network and synced it in fast mode. I'm trying to deploy the contract to Rospten using Truffle framework, but i get the following error (while executing Truffle migrate method)

```
 insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

I understand that this error arises due to lack of ether in my account but i do have a ether in my account that is in the Ropsten network (https://ropsten.etherscan.io). I get 0 when i execute getBalance()

My Account: 0xed055cd2c74efe8f00eb1d0657eb84b2a77ae6d7

Geth node start:

```
     geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

truffle.js:

```
 // Allows us to use ES6 in our migrations and tests.
 require('babel-register')

 module.exports = {
   networks: {
     development: {
       host: '127.0.0.1',
       port: 8545,
       from: "0xed055cd2c74efe8f00eb1d0657eb84b2a77ae6d7",
       network_id: 3, // Match any network id
       gas: 470000
     }
   }
 }
```

Block number containing Transation of Ether : **2871859** https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/2871859

and Transaction Receipt: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x790efa1cec9c2cb6b245da9b13460e0d5214f41f21c197512ef2de2ebbcaa6ff

Downloaded Block data inside geth: 
[image: eth.getBlock(2871859)]

and Transaction Receipt: 
[image: eth.getTransactionReceipt]

eth.syncing

```
 {
   currentBlock: 2871991,
   highestBlock: 2872011,
   knownStates: 29461297,
   pulledStates: 29458752,
   startingBlock: 2871862
 }
```

getBalance in Truffle Console: 
[image: Truffle getBalance]

As you can see I have downloaded the block with my transaction and i have also tried downloading my block in syncemode "full".

I get the same result even when eth.syncing returns false.

I understand that there are already questions like this... but i have tried every one of their answers and its not working...

What am i doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Your node is not fully synced until eth.blockNumber returns a number close to the latest mined block. Until it has finished syncing getting balances might return invalid data.